# InstallShield, registering .Net with IIS after prerequisite install

Tags: asp.net, iis, installshield

I'm fairly new to InstallShield and I'm trying to figure out how to register .Net with IIS in the event that it is installed as a prerequisite. I'd be happy with either a way to determine if a prerequisite was installed to then perform a custom action or a way to synchronously call aspnet_regiis immediately after the .Net install.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using 64 or 32 bit:

On Command Prompt:

```
1. cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
2. aspnet_regiis -i
```